# What is the production ready NonSQL database?

Tags: database, nosql

With the rising of non-sql database usage in high traffic website, I'm interested to use it for my project. Now I've heard several names like [Voldermort](http://project-voldemort.com/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). But which are among these NonSQL database that is production ready? I've seen the download pages and it seems that none of them is production ready because is not version 1.0 yet. Is there any other names other than these 3 that is recommendable to be used in production?

Comment: why are you assuming that high traffic web sites must be using non-SQL databases? Because that's not the case....

Comment: I'm not assuming. It's a reality. I know Facebook and LinkedIn created their own NonSQL database.

Comment: And you seem to be assuming this is the reason Facebook is able to be a high-traffic web site. You also seem to equate SQL and Relational.

Comment: Regarding what DBMS the big sites use there is a thread dedicated to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113381/what-databases-do-webs-biggest-sites-run-on

Comment: @MitchWheat he's not assuming. it's true. RDBMS is does not compete if you want vast, on-demand scalability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to start out from your *project requirements* to see what kind of database you really need. There are many non-relational [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system):s out there and they differ a lot in what kind of problems they are good at solving. I think the article [Should you go Beyond Relational Databases?](http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/should-you-go-beyond-relational-databases/) by [Martin Kleppmann](http://twitter.com/martinkl) is a good starting point for finding out what you need. There's also a lot of stackoverflow threads on similar topics, these are my favorites:

- [The Next-gen Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282783/the-next-gen-databases/)
- [Non-Relational Database Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189911/non-relational-database-design)
- [When shouldn’t you use a relational
  database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667141/when-shouldnt-you-use-a-relational-database)
- [Good reasons NOT to use a relational
  database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823/good-reasons-not-to-use-a-relational-database)

When you have narrowed down what you actually need you can take a deeper look into the alternatives to see which DBMS are production ready *for your use case*. Production readiness isn't a yes/no thing: people may successfully deploy some solution that for example lacks in tool support - in another project this could be a no-go.

As for version numbers different projects have a different take on this, so you can't just compare the version numbers. I'm involved in the graph database project [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) and even if it has been in production use for 5+ years by now we still haven't released a version 1.0 final yet.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. Just saying "I want NoSQL" is not the solution. In fact, it is pretty much the *oppposite* of what NoSQL is all about: taking a look at your requirements and then figuring out what the best representation of your data is. And, BTW, this *includes* SQL, if that indeed happens to be the best tool for the job. However, just "I want NoSQL" is not enough. There are graph DBs, hierarchical DBs, key/value DBs, document DBs, non-SQL relational DBs. You need to figure out which one of those you need, *before* you start picking specific products.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by production ready? As far as I know, all of them are being used on live systems.

You should make your choice based on how the features they provide fit your needs.

You can also add Tokyo Cabinet to the list as well as the mnesia database provided by the Erlang VM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to answer "use SIRA_PRISE".

It's definitely non-SQL.

And its current version is 1.2, meaning that someone like you must definitely assume it's "production-ready".

But perhaps I shouldn't be answering at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nice article comparing rdbms with 'next gen' and listing some providers:

Is the Relational Database Doomed?
http://readwrite.com/2009/02/12/is-the-relational-database-doomed

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use **Arangodb**.

**ArangoDB** is a **multi-model mostly-memory database** with a flexible data model for documents and graphs. It is designed as a “**general purpose database**”, offering all the features you typically need for modern web applications.

**ArangoDB** is supposed to grow with the application—the project may start as a simple single-server prototype, nothing you couldn’t do with a relational database equally well. After some time, some geo-location features are needed and a shopping cart requires transactions. ArangoDB’s graph data model is useful for the recommendation system. The smartphone app needs a lean API to the back-end—this is where Foxx, ArangoDB’s integrated Javascript application framework, comes into play.

Another unique feature is **ArangoDB’s query language AQL** — it makes querying powerful and convenient. AQL enables you to describe complex filter conditions and joins in a readable format, much in the same way as SQL.

**You can model your data in several ways:**

- in key/value pairs
- as collections of documents
- as graphs with nodes, edges, and properties for both

**You can access data in ArangoDB:**

- using the general HTTP REST API via curl/wget, or your browser
- via the **ArangoDB shell** (“arangosh”)
- using a programming language specific client library

**Server requirements for ArangoDB:**

**ArangoDB** runs on **Linux**, **OS X** and **Microsoft Windows**.
It runs on **32bit** and **64bit** systems, though using a **32bit** system will limit you to using only approximately **2 to 3 GB** of data with **ArangoDB**.